# Using values in one column to get means of other columns in R

Tags: r

I'm having some trouble with a bit of code... So I have a dataframe set up something like in the pic below, except it has 1000s of rows and columns. What I want to do is get an average temperature relative to the time each bird's mass was measured. So essentially, I want to take the value in the date of measurement column ("date") (which shows the date in a day of the year format), and tell R to create a new column with the average temperature of the 5 days directly preceding the date of measurement (the columns X46, X47... contain temperature measurements for those days of the year) and thus create an average temperature of a time period relative to each bird. So a supervisor suggested using a for loop, but I really don't know how I can do this...
Any tips/help would be incredibly appreciated as I've been stuck on this for a while...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh6T7.jpg)

Comment: Please share a little bit of reproducible sample data as copy/pasteable text, not as a picture of a notebook. Create something that we can run code on to give you a solution. We don't need 1000s of rows and columns, 2 birds and < 10 dates should be plenty. Providing something we can copy/paste into R to create sample data will make it much easier and faster for people to help you, and remove any ambiguity about your input (including the classes of columns, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a `rowwise`-operation:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(avg_temp = mean(c_across(paste0("X", seq(date, date-4))))) |>
  ungroup()
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 12
  bird_id  mass  date   X53   X52   X51   X50   X49   X48   X47   X46 avg_temp
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1 R1       10.2    52     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8        4
2 R2       14.8    53     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8        3
```

Sample data based on your notebook:

```r
df <- 
  tibble(bird_id = c("R1", "R2"),
         mass = c(10.2, 14.8),
         date = c(52, 53),
         X53 = c(1, 1),
         X52 = c(2, 2),
         X51 = c(3, 3),
         X50 = c(4, 4),
         X49 = c(5, 5),
         X48 = c(6, 6),
         X47 = c(7, 7),
         X46 = c(8, 8))
```

You'd need to think about the situation around the first 5 days in the year.

Comment: harre thank you so much!! I think this actually worked! Just, one last thing if you could help me out with would be amazing, for this bit: "c_across(paste0("X", seq(date, date-4)))" am I asking r to take a sequence of columns starting from the one named "date" and going to 4 columns before that one, or am I asking r to take a sequence of columns where the names correspond to "date" and "date"-4? (So is it by column numbers, or column names?) Asking because I have actually got hourly temperature measurements for about 120 days...

Comment: It constructs a sequence of column names starting with "X" followed by the five dates/numbers :)